# Laravel how to format a subquery

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the following query in MySQL

```
select players.id as id, players.username, 
        players.points, count("*") as total, 
        sum(player_answers.correct = 1) as correct_answers,
        (
            select count(*) as wrong 
            from `player_answers` 
                left join `questions` on `questions`.`id` = `player_answers`.`question_id` 
            where `player_id` = 1379 
            and `questions`.`answer_id` is not null 
            and `player_answers`.`answer_id` <> 'questions.answer_id' 
            and `player_answers`.`correct` <> 1
        ) as wrong_answers
    from `player_answers` 
        left join `questions` on `player_answers`.`question_id` = `questions`.`id` 
        left join `players` on `players`.`id` = `player_answers`.`player_id` 
where `player_answers`.`answer_id` <> 'questions.answer_id' 
and `player_answers`.`correct` <> 1 
group by `players`.`username`, `players`.`id` 
order by `username` asc
```

I'm struggling to write it in Laravel. Can anybody help or point me to the right direction

Comment: So much easier to debug when you can actually see it all

Comment: Do you have models set up for these tables?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something like this

````
$query = DB::table("player_answers")
                    ->select(DB::raw('players.id as id,  players.points, count("*") as total_answered, sum(player_answers.correct = 1) as correct_answers'),
                        DB::raw("(select count(*) as wrong from `player_answers` left join `questions` on `questions`.`id` = `player_answers`.`question_id` where player_answers.player_id = players.id and `questions`.`answer_id` is not null and `player_answers`.`answer_id` <> 'questions.answer_id' and `player_answers`.`correct` <> 1   ) as wrong_answers"))
                            ->leftJoin('questions', 'player_answers.question_id', '=', 'questions.id')
                            ->leftJoin('players', 'players.id', '=', 'player_answers.player_id');```
````